# Numpy efficient way to parse array of string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have this array of strings, that I got from a database query

```
dat = [['1','2 3 4 5'],
['6', '7 8 9 10'],
['11', '12 13 14 15']]
```

From this 3x2 array I have to make a 3x5 array of floats to do my calculations. For now I'm just saving the array to a tmp file and reading the file to get the 3x5 array,

```
np.savetxt(file,dat, fmt="%s\t%s")
np.loadtxt(file)
```

But other than explicitly looping through the elements spliting them them and converting them, is there any more efficient numpy way to do this?

Comment: Use `np.vstack(np.char.split(np.asarray(dat)).sum(axis=1)).astype(np.float)`

Comment: @Mstaino very nice, that should be posted as an answer

Comment: Out of curiosity; what is wrong with for-loops?

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson!

Comment: @GlobalTraveler especially if you're running in numpy, vectorized operations are faster and more efficient in general. In this example, it's not really a big deal, but over larger arrays it could make a large difference. Not to mention it's just better coding practice to vectorize over looping.

Comment: @G.Anderson, @GlobalTraveler, `np.char.split` essentially applies the string method to each element of the array, so there's no time savings compared to a iterative Python approach.

Comment: right @hpaulj that is my point in this case i see no point in shying away from a loop. I am fully aware that vectorized approaches are preferred for numeric purposes. Here the one-liner just obfuscates what is actually going on an would prefer a list comprehension, but that's just personal preference. Anyhoozle  nice find with the char array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
np.vstack(np.char.split(dat).sum(axis=1)).astype(np.float)
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use `np.asarray` ?

Comment: If you omit the `np.array`, `char.splt` does it for you.  Timing's the same either way.

Comment: didn't know that. Thanks @hpaulj. Adding it to improve the answer

Answer (score 2):

Using conventional Python iteration:

```
def foo(row):
    res = []
    for x in row: res.extend(x.split())
    return res
In [141]: np.array([foo(row) for row in dat],int)
Out[141]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

It's noticeably faster than the `np.char.split` approach:

```
In [143]: timeit np.vstack(np.char.split(dat).sum(axis=1)).astype(int)
61 µs ± 171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [144]: timeit np.array([foo(row) for row in dat],int)
8.74 µs ± 239 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And the rejected `fromstring` approach:

```
In [147]: timeit np.array([np.fromstring(' '.join(i), sep=' ') for i in dat],int)
13.9 µs ± 296 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And from the comment:

```
In [256]: timeit np.asarray([' '.join(j for i in dat for j in i).split(' ')], in
     ...: t).reshape(3 ,5)
10.1 µs ± 12.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [253]: ' '.join(j for i in dat for j in i)
Out[253]: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15'
```

In the same spirit - do the string join one row at a time:

```
In [262]: timeit np.array([' '.join(row).split() for row in dat], int)
7.47 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I would like to add my contribution


    `timeit   asarray([' '.join(j for i in dat for j in i).split(' ')]).reshape(3 ,5)`

`4.47 µs ± 33.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Which outperforms all the methods you posted above

Comment: Forgot the dtype argument above, adding it will add 1 microsecond.